# JavaFX объявление @FXML объектов

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Есть ли такой макрос, который автоматически генерировал в коде все объекты из file.fxml?

Comment: В idea есть функция биндинга параметров из файла

Comment: В `SceneBuilder`  view -> show_sample_controller_skeleton